# How do I specify a JSON variable name for a PowerShell class property?

Tags: json, powershell

I have a sample PowerShell script that defines a class "Archive" with a few properties:

```
class Archive {
    [String]$Address #JSON: archive
    [Int]$Port #JSON: port
    [String]$SiteKey #JSON site-key

    Archive() {
        $this.Address = "127.0.0.1"
        $this.Port = 80
    }
}

$a = [Archive]::new()

$json = $a | ConvertTo-Json

$json
```

I am trying to create a simple script that takes a few values and outputs it as a JSON. At first, I disregarded naming conventions in PowerShell to match the names. Then I added a property name with a hyphen (which isn't part of the naming requirements for variables).

I've come from a C# perspective where I'd use [[DataMember(Name = "api-name")]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute) attributes to hint the name to use when using APIs' JSON payloads.

Is there a way to provide naming hints to a PowerShell property so that when the object is passed to `ConvertTo-Json` it will use the hint rather than the actual name of the property in the script?

### Edits

1. Underscores are allowed. Hyphens are not. Need to support something like `$field-name`

Answer (score 0):

You can specify [variable names that include special characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_variables?view=powershell-6#variable-names-that-include-special-characters) by surrounding the name with curly brackets.

For example, you can use:

```
class Archive {
    [String]$address
    [Int]$port
    [String]${site_key} # variable / property name with special characters

    Archive() {
        $this.address = "127.0.0.1"
        $this.port = 80
        $this.{site_key} = "site key"
    }
}

$a = [Archive]::new()

$json = $a | ConvertTo-Json

$json
```

Which should give you this JSON output:

```
{
    "address":  "127.0.0.1",
    "port":  80,
    "site_key":  "site key"
}
```

When you execute `ConvertTo-Json`, it will still use the names but this way you can write variable names as anything.

Unfortunately, it does not seem to apply to class names.